# Create a JSONArray using a while loop in PHP

Tags: php, json

I will be sending the array to java in order to populate a ListView,  how do I get the following code to output an array?:

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'uopuser';

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die('Unable to connect');


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT * FROM society');
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $society_id, $name, $email, $description);

$society = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $society['society_id'] = $society_id;
    $society['name'] = $name;
    $society['email'] = $email;
    $society['description'] = $description;
    echo json_encode($society);
}

echo json_encode($society);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Rather than:

```
{"society_id":1,"name":"TestName1","email":"Test@email1","description":"TestDes1"}
{"society_id":2,"name":"TestName2","email":"Test@email2","description":"TestDes2"}
{"society_id":3,"name":"TestName3","email":"Test@email3","description":"TestDes3"}
```

I've looked about the internet before posting this but am seriously confused! Thanks to anyone in advance.

Comment: you can do like this: $societies = array(); $societies.push($society);  echo json_encode($societies);
push the $society to $societies array inside the loop and outside this loop you just encode.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array, you're going one step too far, and also missing one step. You're creating an array in your while function, but you don't need to use json_encode unless you're passing it to something that needs it in json format. To make one big array, just create another array:

```
$society = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $new_soc = array();
    $new_soc['society_id'] = $society_id;
    $new_soc['name'] = $name;
    $new_soc['email'] = $email;
    $new_soc['description'] = $description;
    //$new_soc is now a single array. You add it to the larger array next
    $society[] = $new_soc;
}
```

Now you can do whatever you need to do with the large $society array.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned, I will be passing this to Java in order to populate a ListView.

Comment: Once you're done with the while statement, you can do json_encode on $society, and it will contain all of your results.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want an output in form of an array then why are you encoding it to JSON? you can simply use,

```
print_r($society);
```

P.S. if you are doing this for an AJAX call then using this json_encode function is better. You can just use **JSON.parse()** method on in your JavaScript code for parsing the received response.